# Error While DeserializeObject if string contains Double Quotes

Tags: c#, json, webapi

```
public class SearchResult : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposedValue;

        public int RecordCount { get; set; }
        public List<FilterResult> FilterResult { get; set; }


        public SearchResult()
        {
            RecordCount = 0;
            this.FilterResult = new List<FilterResult>();
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    RecordCount = 0;

                    if (FilterResult != null)
                        FilterResult.Clear();
                    FilterResult = null;

                }

                // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
                // TODO: set large fields to null
                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
        // ~SearchResult()
        // {
        //     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        //     Dispose(disposing: false);
        // }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    public class FilterResult
    {
        public double RowNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("A.R.F.No")]
        public double ARFNo { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Label4 { get; set; }
        public string Label5 { get; set; }
        public string Label6 { get; set; }
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public string td_dnimer_pxe { get; set; }
        public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
        public string DocumentVersion { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Expiry Date")]
        public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public string MainFileName { get; set; }
        public string MainFileExt { get; set; }
        public string DocTitle { get; set; }
        public string td_ffe { get; set; }
        public string td_hsilbup { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string DeletedOn { get; set; }

        public FilterResult()
        {
            ARFNo = 0;
            Company = string.Empty;
            Location = string.Empty;
            Department = string.Empty;
            Label4 = string.Empty;
            Label5 = string.Empty;
            Label6 = string.Empty;
            DocumentType = string.Empty;
            td_dnimer_pxe = string.Empty;
            DocumentNo = string.Empty;
            DocumentVersion = string.Empty;
            ExpiryDate = string.Empty;
            MainFileName = string.Empty;
            MainFileExt = string.Empty;
            DocTitle = string.Empty;
            td_ffe = string.Empty;
            td_hsilbup = string.Empty;
            Status = string.Empty;
            DeletedOn = string.Empty;
        }
        ~FilterResult()
        {
            ARFNo = 0;
            Company = string.Empty;
            Location = string.Empty;
            Department = string.Empty;
            Label4 = string.Empty;
            Label5 = string.Empty;
            Label6 = string.Empty;
            DocumentType = string.Empty;
            td_dnimer_pxe = string.Empty;
            DocumentNo = string.Empty;
            DocumentVersion = string.Empty;
            ExpiryDate = string.Empty;
            MainFileName = string.Empty;
            MainFileExt = string.Empty;
            DocTitle = string.Empty;
            td_ffe = string.Empty;
            td_hsilbup = string.Empty;
            Status = string.Empty;
            DeletedOn = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

My json String

```
string szResponse = "{\"RecordCount\":\"1\",\"FilterResult\":\"[{\\\"RowNumber\\\":1,\\\"A.R.F.No\\\":16970.0,\\\"Company\\\":\\\"Educe\\\",\\\"Location\\\":\\\"Pune\\\",\\\"Department\\\":\\\"DEV\\\",\\\"Label4\\\":\\\"NA\\\",\\\"Label5\\\":\\\"NA\\\",\\\"Label6\\\":\\\"NA\\\",\\\"DocumentType\\\":\\\"CheckImbededImages\\\",\\\"td_dnimer_pxe\\\":null,\\\"DocumentNo\\\":\\\"Doc/~12~\\\",\\\"DocumentVersion\\\":\\\"1.00\\\",\\\"Expiry Date\\\":\\\"2121-08-08T00:00:00\\\",\\\"MainFileName\\\":\\\"16970\\\",\\\"MainFileExt\\\":\\\"docx\\\",\\\"DocTitle\\\":\\\"Test ImbededImages \\\\\\\"\\\",\\\"td_ffe\\\":\\\"2022-08-09T00:00:00\\\",\\\"td_hsilbup\\\":null,\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"DeletedOn\\\":\\\"2022-08-09T00:00:00\\\"}]\"}";
var Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(szResponse);
```

for above Conversion I'm Getting Error

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path
> 'FilterResult[0].DocTitle'

How i Can handle double Quote in Above Jason String
string **szResponse** is the Response from WEB API Method and I'm Trying To Convert it to object SearchResult
tried different Solutions provided but didn't Work

Comment: Off-topic: Your code looks like it was written by someone with a C++ background who has very little idea about proper C# memory management. You almost never want to write a finalizer in everyday application code, and your Dispose method also looks completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not simply a JSON structure. It is JSON where the "FilterResult" property of the top level object is itself JSON. You can deserialize it in two steps as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                
public class SearchResult
{
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public string FilterResult { get; set; }
}

public class FilterResult
{
        public double RowNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("A.R.F.No")]
        public double ARFNo { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Label4 { get; set; }
        public string Label5 { get; set; }
        public string Label6 { get; set; }
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public string td_dnimer_pxe { get; set; }
        public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
        public string DocumentVersion { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Expiry Date")]
        public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public string MainFileName { get; set; }
        public string MainFileExt { get; set; }
        public string DocTitle { get; set; }
        public string td_ffe { get; set; }
        public string td_hsilbup { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string DeletedOn { get; set; }
}
   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string szResponse = "{\"RecordCount\":\"1\",\"FilterResult\":\"[{\\\"RowNumber\\\":1,\\\"A.R.F.No\\\":16970.0,\\\"Company\\\":\\\"Educe\\\",\\\"Location\\\":\\\"Pune\\\",\\\"Department\\\":\\\"DEV\\\",\\\"Label4\\\":\\\"NA\\\",\\\"Label5\\\":\\\"NA\\\",\\\"Label6\\\":\\\"NA\\\",\\\"DocumentType\\\":\\\"CheckImbededImages\\\",\\\"td_dnimer_pxe\\\":null,\\\"DocumentNo\\\":\\\"Doc/~12~\\\",\\\"DocumentVersion\\\":\\\"1.00\\\",\\\"Expiry Date\\\":\\\"2121-08-08T00:00:00\\\",\\\"MainFileName\\\":\\\"16970\\\",\\\"MainFileExt\\\":\\\"docx\\\",\\\"DocTitle\\\":\\\"Test ImbededImages \\\\\\\"\\\",\\\"td_ffe\\\":\\\"2022-08-09T00:00:00\\\",\\\"td_hsilbup\\\":null,\\\"Status\\\":0,\\\"DeletedOn\\\":\\\"2022-08-09T00:00:00\\\"}]\"}";
        var Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(szResponse);
        
        var filterResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FilterResult>>(Result.FilterResult);
    }
}
```